# Hide Div based on select box using data-type not ID/Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to hide DIV based on the value of a select box (the select box doesn't have a unique ID or class). The only unique way I can see to possibly target it, is it has 'Data-type="location"'

`<div class="bookly-form-group" data-type="location"><label>Location</label> <div><select><option value="0">Select location</option><option value="3">A Club</option><option value="4">B Club</option><option value="1">C Club</option><option value="6">Mobile Hire</option></select></div> </div>`

On the drop-down code above, if the user selects "Mobile Hire" it should then show the DIV pasted below...otherwise the DIV should be hidden.

`<div class="bookly-form-group" data-type="duration"><label>Duration</label> <div><select><option value="3">3 h (£120.00)</option><option value="4">4 h (£160.00)</option><option value="5">5 h (£200.00)</option><option value="6">6 h (£240.00)</option><option value="7">7 h (£280.00)</option><option value="8">8 h (£320.00)</option></select></div> </div>`

Comment: Is the `<div>` directly below the `<select>`? Actually post jQuery/JavaScript and HTML as a [mcve]. Although I suspect your problem to be an easy fix, I'd rather not play 20 questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Code, this should work:

```
 //initially hide duration div
 $('div[data-type="duration"]').hide();

 $('div[data-type="location"] select').on('change' ,(function () {
    var value = $('div[data-type="location"] select option:selected').text();
    if(value === "Mobile Hire") {
        $('div[data-type="duration"]').show();
    }
    else {
        $('div[data-type="duration"]').hide();
    }
  }));
```

Comment: Amazing that works perfectly thank you very much! Is it possible to hide the duration div immediately rather than on select change? (i.e so nobody ever sees the duration div unless they've selected Mobile Hire)

Comment: Sure, I edited the code to include this logic, please check it.

Comment: Hey @smabrar, welcome to Stack Overflow! Great you helped OP with a solution, however next time you should consider editing your original answer instead of posting a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is done by the following code:

```
//First Import JQuery CDN, then Following Code inside a script tag

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('div[data-type="location"] select').on('change' , (function () {
      $('div[data-type="duration"]').hide();
  }));
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. That hides the div successfully but I need it to be hidden but then show when one of the select options ("Mobile Hire") within "location" is selected. Is there perhaps a tweak to your code that says hide the div unless the selected value in location contains "Mobile Hire"

Comment: Okay, do check the new code, I fixed it.